# CSRF Session token not working

Tags: php, session, csrf

My session is not being set and I'm not sure why...

```
public static function generate( $key )
{
    $extra = self::$doOriginCheck ? sha1( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) : '';
    $token = base64_encode( time() . $extra . self::randomString( 32 ) );
    $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ] = $token;
    return $token;
}
```

I use that to generate a key. On my log in form, after including my session file, I use:

```
$token = CSRF::generate("token"); // class name is CSRF
```

I then use it `$token` as a hidden value which is submitted along with the form.

Now to check it, I use a function called check() (this is the part where the exception is thrown:

```
public static function check( $key, $origin, $throwException=false, $timespan=null, $multiple=false )
    {
        if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ] ) )
            if($throwException)
                throw new Exception( 'Missing session token.' );
            else
                return false;
                ....
```

I'm checking it as following:

```
CSRF::check($token, $_POST, true, 60*10, false);
```

($token is the token submitted). **Why is is not saving the token in the session?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing $token in as the first parameter for CSRF::check(). Surely, it should be:

```
CSRF::check('token', $_POST, true, 60*10, false);
```

instead of

```
CSRF::check($token, $_POST, true, 60*10, false);
```

Seeing as you're setting the key as 'token' in CSRF::generate? Otherwise:

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'csrf_' . $key ] ) )
```

will be something like:

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'csrf_hed97988hdbnbnuihg07dede89723tg7yihoi3dh' ] ) )
```

Comment: @user2738336 Don't worry. Been having a few brainfarts of my own today!